# Using a stored procedure in my view?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this stored procedure for 'Code' with one input parameter and two return values. Now, I want to use this stored procedure in my view but I don't know how.

This my stored procedure:

```
Create PROC [Document].[sp_SetDefault](
    @Code int,
    @ResultCodeString varchar(50) OUTPUT,
    @ResultCode INT OUTPUT) 
as 
begin 
   if(@Code=1) 
   begin
     set @ResultCodeString='...'
   end
   else 
   begin
       set @ResultCode=@Code 
   end
return 
End
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You need a value for `@Code` when calling your stored procedure - where is this value going to come from in your view??

Comment: The idea of calling a procedure from a view is like... an idea to call a method from a constant variable in a procedural language. It sounds just like nonsense if you understand what `view` and `procedure` are in substance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a stored procedure from a view.  A view is essentially an alias for one SELECT Statement; a stored procedure is a collection of statements (SELECT or UPDATE or anything at all).

The simplest way to use what you have written is to just re-express it within your view. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW someview AS 
SELECT Code, 
       case Code when 1 then '...' else NULL end AS ResultCodeString,
       case Code when 1 then NULL else Code as ResultCode
FROM MyTable
GO
```